# Hibernate Auditing with Envers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to implement auditing using Envers in my Spring-hibernate based web application.Unfortunately,the audit tables are not being created.I don't see errors too.All what I did was include the latest envers jar file in the class path and use the annotation @Audited in the hibernate Domain object.As per the latest Envers documentation,there is no need to specify the listeners in the config file.Not sure what I am missing here.Please help.

Thanks